# Is there a way to get SendInput to work with an application using GDK?

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, gdk

I have an application that can successfully inject keyboard input using the `SendInput` API with the UNICODE flag set. This causes `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_KEYDOWN` messages to be generated with the VK code of E7 (`VK_PACKET`), which gets appropriately translated into the correct WM_CHAR message. This works in all the applications I have tried except for Pidgin, which uses GDK. GDK seems to only look for `WM_KEYUP` messages. Since the ones being generated here don't actually have any indication of the input character (only the `WM_CHAR` does), the input is ignored. Is there a way I could get around this. I haven't had much luck if I use SendInput without the UNICODE flag.

Comment: I too have same issue. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, I used the clipboard as a workaround.  A better way is to use `WM_CHAR`, and if I find a way to send Unicode characters with `WM_CHAR`, I'll update my answer.  Since GTK+ is open source, you can contribute to it and help them (I'm a beginner with C).